Categorification of spectral sequence
All sorts of things are categorified. What about spectral sequences?
Question: What is a categorification of a spectral sequence?
Talking through my hat, I could imagine an $\infty$-category (categorification of the abelian category of spectral sequences) with an $\infty$-functor (limit) into another $\infty$-category (categorification of homotopy or cohomology). Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

If one takes the view that the data of a spectral sequence is equivalent to the data of the filtered object, the following might be relevant. https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.01017
